# Are Guava's toImmutableSet() and toImmutableList() collectors thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, guava, collectors

Guava has collectors like [`ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#toImmutableSet()) and [`ImmutableList.toImmutableList()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#toImmutableList()). Are they thread-safe? Is it safe to use them with parallel streams?

As far as I see the use the regular builders which are not thread-safe:

```
private static final Collector<Object, ?, ImmutableSet<Object>> TO_IMMUTABLE_SET =
    Collector.of(
        ImmutableSet::<Object>builder,
        ImmutableSet.Builder::add,
        ImmutableSet.Builder::combine,
        ImmutableSet.Builder::build);
```

On the other hand, the first and third parameters of `Collector.of()` makes it suspicious that JDK could create a separate builder for every parallel thread and combine their result to make it thread-safe.

Comment: It seems that they are, since they are `extending` from `ImmutableCollection` which is thread-safe. https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html

Comment: @Aman No, not really — `ImmutableCollection#Builder` (and its sublasses), which are used in `TO_IMMUTABLE_SET ` `Collector`, don't extend `ImmutableCollection`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870744/is-guavas-immutablelist-builder-thread-safe).

Comment: @Xaerxess thank you, I didn't know that it used a builder. It's clear that builders are non thread safe.

Comment: All correctly implemented collectors are thread safe when being used correctly. You don’t need to guess from the parameters, how a collector is supposed to be used. That’s what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) is for. There’s also [a section in the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

Answer (score 3):

I believe answer to the question you're supposed to ask is different than to what you actually asked.

No, the collectors are not thread-safe per se (ex. ImmutableList builder performs unsynchronized operations on `Object[]`), but more importantly **collectors don't have to be thread safe to be useful for parallel stream operations**. For that see [answer from Stuart Marks to question "Parallel streams, collectors and thread safety"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350288/parallel-streams-collectors-and-thread-safety):

> > Can non-concurrent collectors be safely used with a parallel stream or should I only use the concurrent versions when collecting from a parallel stream?
>
> It is safe to use a non-concurrent collector in a collect operation of a parallel stream.

For more details, please read the answer and links provided to documentation / contracts of various `java.util.stream` classes.